# Determining hardness and HP of magical items

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I know there is an easy way to determine the hardness and HP of magical weapons and armor but what about items?

One of my player's has a *banner of storm's eye* (*Magic Item Compendium*), constructed of a backpack frame of wood and a banner of cloth, as this is a magic item costing 15K. How does one determine what HP and hardness and item like this has?

Should I be using the HP and hardness of a normal item of wooden construction? aka hardness 5 and hp 10 per 1inch of thickness? Or would this get additional hardness and HP as it is a magical item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the normal hardness and HP for wood.

From the main 3.5 FAQ:

> Magic items that have no enhancement bonuses—which is almost
>   everything except weapons, shields, and armor—have no extra hardness
>   or hit points. For example, a paper scroll has a hardness of 0 and 1
>   hit point, no matter how many spells it contains.

Putting enhancements (ex. a +1 sword) onto armor or weapons is what increases hardness and HP. A magic item that doesn't have that enhancement has no special protection from damage.

Comment: It might be worth a mention, the various ways of boosting the hardness of said items, even if it wasn't specifically asked. Or at least that there are ways.